# Reload dropdownlist after popup window closed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist populated by my database and a button on my page1, now when I click the button page2 will popup which contains of 1 textbox and 2 buttons, if I enter a value in my textbox and click the save button, it'll save on my database and when i click the close button, popup will close then what I want is my dropdown on page1 will reload (without reloading the entire page) in order to get the value that I entered in popup window. This is what I have got so far:

Page1:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('Entry.aspx','','height=200,width=650');return false");

}
```

Page2:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (txtfname.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            lblname.Text = "First Name Required";
            lblname.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (txtlname.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            lbllname.Text = "Last name Required";
            lbllname.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GATE-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbProfile;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", txtlname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mname", txtmname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", txtfname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkbox1", CheckBox1.Checked);

            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox("successfully saved!");
            clear();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        throw exe;
    }
}
protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   Response.Write("window.opener.location.reload();self.close();"); 
}
```

Someone kindly help me with this. i am using asp.net with c#. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function in the parent window that loads the Dropdown by ajax.

to call that function from the popup:

```
window.onunload = reloadDropDown;
function reloadDropDown() {
    window.opener.reloadDropDown();
}
```

create a function named 'reloadDropDown' in the parent window and write code to reload the values using ajax...

Hope it helps.

Plz do comment if you have any issues regarding my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write inside btnClose_Click

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>;window.close();</script>");
```

and add following script to Entry.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        var loc = window.opener.location;
        window.opener.location = loc;

    }

</script>
```

Comment: hello thanks for replying, have tried your codes but still the entire page is refreshing, what I am trying is only the dropdown will reload. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add your dropdownlist in an `UpdatePanel` and when you click on 'Close' button just use  `__doPostBack()` to update UpdatePanel only and not the entire page.

Write following code onclick of close button in javascript-

```
onclick="__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');"
```

ASP.NET AJAX framework will intercept the postback and will fire a partial postback here.

**Although it's a bad practice to call __doPostBack() directly but it can serve your pourpose.**